# How to close program after closing another program?

Tags: cmd.exe

I have `blah.exe` and `blah2.exe`

I want to close `blah2.exe` and the `cmd` window after `blah.exe` finishes working.

Which command should I use to do this?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? It's very unclear and broad at this point.

Comment: You run blah2close.exe.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that starts Notepad and then MS Paint. If you terminate Paint, then the CMD proceeds to kill Notepad.

```
start notepad.exe
mspaint.exe
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
pause
```

Notes:

*Pause* is not required; it keeps the CMD window to enable debugging.

**If there is more than one instance of Notepad running, all will close.**